# how to get from Stream using FlatMap List<> of items with List

Tags: java-stream, flatmap

I have a Collection of a Dto (Pojo).

```
Collection<Dto> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
... <filling dto> now it has items.
```

Dto has a field List:

```
class Dto {
  private List<Tag> tags; 
} 

@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Tag {
  private String name;

}
```

Example of Data:

```
dtos.get(1) => new Tag('name1.1') -> new Tag('name1.2') 
dtos.get(2) => new Tag('name2.1') 
dtos.get(3) => new Tag('name3.1') > new Tag('name3.2')
dtos.get(4) => null
```

a QUESTIONL How to get using only stream Java8+ all List
is it possible to use flatMap()

You ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be straightforward, you filter the `null` tags then `flatmap` them and `collect` to a list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dto dto1 = new Dto(Arrays.asList(new Tag("name1.1"), new Tag("name1.2")));
    Dto dto2 = new Dto(Arrays.asList(new Tag("name2.1")));
    Dto dto3 = new Dto(Arrays.asList(new Tag("name3.1"), new Tag("name3.2")));
    Dto dto4 = new Dto(null);

    Collection<Dto> dtos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dto1, dto2, dto3, dto4));

    List<Tag> tags = dtos.stream().filter(dto -> dto.getTags() != null).flatMap(dto ->
            dto.getTags().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```